# POST Request - Multipart/form-data

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8, multipartform-data

I am trying to make a multipart/form-data post request with an image upload and keep getting errors like {"errors":[{"status":400,"message":"Missing multipart field ‘operations’...}. Don't really know my error as Ive tried several different ways to solve it. What would be the best way to send the parameters? A successful image upload looks like this (server output):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryuDx6GgSAqYi8E7YF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="operations"

{"operationName":"uploadTempListingPhotos","variables":{"input":{"photos":[null]}},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"c6965bfe2119479193f340d936ce2f772606a623ff66da18c01a43v222f88460"}}}
------WebKitFormBoundaryuDx6GgSAqYi8E7YF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="map"

{"1":["variables.input.photos.0"]}
------WebKitFormBoundaryuDx6GgSAqYi8E7YF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryuDx6GgSAqYi8E7YF--
```

and my current code:

```
func multiFormPOST() {
        
        ///generate the boundary
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        let mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        let imageData = UIImage(named: "formImage")!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        
        let params: [String : Any] = [
            "operationName": "uploadTempListingPhotos",
            "variables": ["input":
                            ["photos":[nil]]],
            "extensions": ["persistedQuery":
                            ["version": 1,
                            "sha256Hash":"c6965bfe2119479193f340d936ce2f772606a623ff66da18c01a43v222f88460"]]
        ]
        
        let map: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
            "1": ["variables.input.photos.0"]
        ]
        
        var body = Data()
        let boundaryPrefix = " — \(boundary)\r\n"
        
        ///operations
        if let operationsData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted), let operationJSONText = String(data: operationsData, encoding: .ascii) {
            body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
            body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"operations\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
            body.append(Data("\(operationJSONText)\r\n".utf8))
        }
//        for (key, value) in params {
//            body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
//            body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
//            body.append(Data("\(value)\r\n".utf8))
//        }
//        body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
//        body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"operations\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
//        body.append(Data("\(operationJSONText)\r\n".utf8))
        
        ///map
        if let mapData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: map, options: .prettyPrinted), let mapJSONText = String(data: mapData, encoding: .ascii) {
            body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
            body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"map\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
            body.append(Data("\(mapJSONText)\r\n".utf8))
        }
//        for (key, value) in map {
//            body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
//            body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
//            body.append(Data("\(value)\r\n".utf8))
//        }
//        body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
//        body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"map\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
//        body.append(Data("\(mapJSONText)\r\n".utf8))
        
        ///image
        body.append(Data(boundaryPrefix.utf8))
        body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"1\"; filename=\"blob\"\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(Data("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(Data(imageData!))
        body.append(Data("\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(Data(" — ".appending(boundary.appending(" — ")).utf8))
        
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: "urlHere") else {
            return
        }
        
        var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("gzip, deflate", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = body
        
//        if let jsonParamData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted), let theJSONText = String(data: jsonParamData, encoding: .ascii) {
//                print(theJSONText)
//                request.httpBody = jsonParamData
//        }
//
//        if let jsonMapData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: map, options: .prettyPrinted), let theJSONText = String(data: jsonMapData, encoding: .ascii) {
//                print(theJSONText)
//                request.httpBody = jsonMapData
//        }
//        request.httpBody = imageData
//

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, let res = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(res)
            } else {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use multer. 
npm install multer
This is one of the best middleware for multipart upload.

Comment: The boundaries that you are adding do not look correct. It should be two hyphens, `--`, followed by the boundary, without any spaces. But you appear the have an en or em-dash and extra spaces…

Comment: Same thing for the final terminating `--` after the last boundary…

Comment: I would advise libraries like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) if you want to get out of the weeds in creating network requests manually.

Comment: Completely unrelated, I’d advise against putting JSON inside multipart request. Pick one or the other.